# css marquee overlay: hidden and max height not working

Tags: css, marquee

Regarding this `marquee` snippet,..

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 10em
  }
  100% {
    top: -2em
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">text</p>
```

... `overlay: hidden` is not working and `max-height` is not working too.
The text must keep scrolling 'behind' the image and the text must start scroll 'respecting' the height (410px).

Follows the url wheres the marquee is placed festasparapalmoemeio.pt to a better understanding about the issues and to be able to helping me to solve them.

Soon as possible.

Please!

Comment: Your CSS selector saying ".marquee p" but you used ".marquee" in "p" tag, then how this selector working here?

Comment: Thx Hanif for your will to help me. dispite your willing,.. the snippet you provided doesnt works,.. at least for the place I want it. Ill keep the less bad snippet (with color font and animation speed issues) until someone tell me the way to solve them.